# What is the type of chunks delivered to http.IncomingMessage in NodeJS

Tags: node.js

If using http server functionality of NodeJS, the request is of type [`http.IncomingMessage`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_incomingmessage) that implements [`stream.Readable`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_readable).

The data events emitted by `Readable` can have arguments of type `String` or `Buffer`.

For `IncomingMessage`, I seem to be receiving string arguments for data events. It's unclear to me why, considering that HTTP body data is better represented by `Buffer`. The documentation, however, doesn't say what would be the type of the argument.

Will the type of the argument always be `String`, or are there conditions (including the ones that I can control from the program side) when the reader may emit `Buffer` arguments instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no default encoding for (`http.IncomingMessage`) streams, so you will get `Buffer` objects and not strings. If you call `.setEncoding()` though, then you *will* get strings of whatever type you specify.

If you're buffering the data *with a string*, then of course you will see "string data" appended because then `buffer.toString()` is implicitly being called when you concatenate the `Buffer` to your string buffer variable. For example:

```
var buf = '';
req.on('data', function(data) {
  // Here `data.toString()` is called implicitly because you a
  // non-string object has to be converted somehow in order to be
  // added to `buf`. When this implicit conversion happens, the result
  // will be the concatenation of `buf` + `data` converted to a UTF-8
  // string because that is the default encoding argument for
  // `buffer.toString()`
  buf += data;
  // You can even check that it's a buffer with:
  console.log(Buffer.isBuffer(data));
});
```

Comment: ty. I missed `.setEncoding()` method. I saw them as "strings" because I sent them to debug, and they looked like text, buffers usually show as `<Buffer ...>`, but that was because of concatenation. And there is no way to undo `.setEncoding`, or so it seems.

Comment: Technically you *can* removing an encoding set by `.setEncoding()` by unsetting part of the internal Readable state, but that's not a public API.